# Why do I get different result in linear programming problem (using pulp)

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have written some code in python using the pulp library, in order to solve a linear problem. However, I get different results if I change the y variable's name to s or r and rerun the program. By different results I mean the variables x1,x2 ... x10 and y1...y10 that are being printed. However the minimum value stays the same at 36650.

The code is the following:

```
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable, LpMinimize

model = LpProblem(name="resource", sense=LpMinimize)

x = {i: LpVariable(name=f"x{i}", lowBound=0) for i in range(1, 11)}
y = {i: LpVariable(name=f"y{i}", lowBound=0) for i in range(1, 11)}

model += (x[1] + 50 - y[1] >= 100 , "x1")
model += (x[2] + y[1] - y[2] >= 200 , "x2")
model += (x[3] + y[2] - y[3] >= 150 , "x3")
model += (x[4] + y[3] - y[4] >= 400 , "x4")
model += (x[5] + y[4] - y[5] >= 300 , "x5")
model += (x[6] + y[5] - y[6] >= 400 , "x6")
model += (x[7] + y[6] - y[7] >= 150 , "x7")
model += (x[8] + y[7] - y[8] >= 150 , "x8")
model += (x[9] + y[8] - y[9] >= 200 , "x9")
model += (x[10] + y[9] - y[10] >= 250 , "x10")
model += (0 <= x[1] <= 400 , "ti")
model += (0 <= x[2] <= 500 , "tii")
model += (0 <= x[3] <= 300 , "tiii")
model += (0 <= x[4] <= 400 , "tiv")
model += (0 <= x[5] <= 400 , "tv")
model += (0 <= x[6] <= 300 , "tvi")
model += (0 <= x[7] <= 300 , "tvii")
model += (0 <= x[8] <= 500 , "tviii")
model += (0 <= x[9] <= 500 , "tix")
model += (0 <= x[10] <= 300 , "tx")

model += 13*x[1] + 15*x[2] + 17*x[3] + 19*x[4] + 17*x[5] + 18*x[6] + 14*x[7] + 12*x[8] + 14*x[9] + 15*x[10] + 2*y[1] + 2*y[2] + 2*y[3] + 2*y[4] + 2*y[5] + 2*y[6] + 2*y[7] + 2*y[8] + 2*y[9] + 2*y[10]

status = model.solve()

print(f"The minimal total cost is: {model.objective.value()}")

for var in x.values():
    print(f"{var.name}: {var.value()}")
for var in y.values():
    print(f"{var.name}: {var.value()}")
```

The full results can be seen below
[image: Results comparison]

Comment: Looks fishy (I expect the obj to change). You may want to print the LP file of both versions and compare.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thank you, it seems that when using variables x and y , the program evaluates first the x and then the y. But in x and s, s is evaluated first (because it comes first in the alphabet). Hence the difference in the solutions

Comment: Yes. The obj seems to be indeed the same for these two solutions, so you problem has multiple optimal solutions. Any change in the model (like changing the variable ordering) can lead the solver to find a different optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example

```
>>> x = pulp.LpVariable('x',0, 3, pulp.LpInteger)
>>> y = pulp.LpVariable('y',0, 3, pulp.LpInteger)
>>> prob = pulp.LpProblem('example', pulp.LpMaximize)
>>> prob += x+y  
>>> prob += x+y <= 3
```

The optimal value is **3**, but there are several (x,y) pairs that lead to this optimal value, i.e., `(3,0), (2,1), (1,2), (0,3)`.